# Does Hyper-V Handle Network Traffic Efficiently Between VMs?

Tags: networking, virtualization, hyper-v

If I have network traffic between two VMs on the same Hyper-V host does the traffic actually ever leave the host server? How can I tell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, and in fact it is very efficient between parent OS and the VM's too.

The reason is that it setups up a virtual switch which all use and pass traffic that way without needing to go via the network cards/interfaces.

[image] - From [Understanding Network with Hyper-V](http://blogs.msdn.com/virtual_pc_guy/archive/2008/01/08/understanding-networking-with-hyper-v.aspx), which is a great blog post on the topic